# Elastic search fetching wrong

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have following code.

```
<?php

$params = [
    'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
    'type' => $this->client->getType(),
    "from" => 0, "size" => 1000,
    "scroll" => "1m",
    'body' => [
        "query" => [
            "multi_match" => [
                "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                "type" => "best_fields",
                "query" => $query
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

If I search for 'Samsung mobile' it returns other result too. I want it to display only specific record. Anyone please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Result:

```
[19] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 12186
                [lang_id] => 1
                [manuf_id] => 5
                [cat_type_id] => 2
                [cat_id] => 3
                [network_id] => 0
                [comp_group_id] => 0
                [prod_name] => Samsung J700 mobile phone Silver Unlocked Sim Free
                [prod_short_name] => 
                [prod_color] => 0
                [prod_seo_name] => simfree-samsung-j700-silver-unlocked
)
 [999] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 12074
                [lang_id] => 1
                [manuf_id] => 7
                [cat_type_id] => 2
                [cat_id] => 3
                [network_id] => 0
                [comp_group_id] => 0
                [prod_name] => LG KU990i Viewty Mobile Phone Unlocked Sim Free
                [prod_short_name] => 
                [prod_color] => 0
                [prod_seo_name] => simfree-lg-viewty-unlocked
)
```

what exactly I can do to fire '=' query instead of  'LIKE' query

Comment: Do you want to check both the fields(`prod_name ` and `prod_seo_name`) for exact match?

Comment: No..Either one or both ..Like If I search "Samsung unlocked" than it should not return "LG unlocked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `type` of `multi_match` to `phrase` or `phrase_prefix` which uses phrase search instead of simple matching.

```
"multi_match" => [
                "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                "query" => $query
            ]
```

See this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-phrase